# How to listen for global clicks in c using windows system libraries?

Tags: c, click, global

I want to be able to listen for global clicks in c for example in pseudocode

```
on("globalClick") {
    do(stuff);
};
```

Comment: There's no standard C API for handling mouse operations. You need to use window system libraries.

Comment: ISO C does not have a notion of a mouse. Therefore, what you are asking for is not possible in plain ISO C. However, most operating systems offer some sort of API which provides the functionality that you desire. Therefore, in order for your question to be answerable, you will have to specify which operating system your question appies to.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: probably more _windowing system_ than _operating system_. There are many such libraries, and the answer is likely different for each one.

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes, for some operating systems, such as Linux, the next question will probably be which window manager the question applies to. However, for some operating systems, such as Microsoft Windows, this question will not apply. That is why I am only asking one question at a time.